# Adding plain text to a Nuke simple panel window

Tags: python, text, panel, nuke

I work with Nuke all the time and I know simple Python to create simple tools in it. I’ve been able to carry out moderately complicated actions with panels and tools but I am stuck with something that should be very simple, but I can’t seem to find the answer here or in nukepedia or in the foundry help and tutorials. I want to add some simple text to my panel. For example:

```
p = nuke.Panel('test')
p.message('This is where I hope to display an explanation of the tool')
p.addButton('Quit')
```

Where I use `p.message` just as a placeholder for what I need.

Any help would be appreciated, I feel like this is so simple that it isn’t included in most of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks! It is not exactly what I had in mind but it did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows containing a simple message use this code:

```
nuke.message('Description of the tool')
```

If you need `yes`/`no` choice, use this code:

```
if nuke.ask('Would you like to create a ColorWheel node?'):
    nuke.createNode('ColorWheel')
```

In case you need a panel, use the following code:

```
panel = nuke.Panel('Test panel')
panel.addNotepad('Description here','Description of the Tool')
panel.addButton('Quit')
```

...and then just call:

```
panel.show()
```